# bootstrap mobile menu is not working collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, menu

My mobile menu is not working and I can not find the error.

Could someone help me solve it please?
http://emblema78.com/xiis/

thanks in advance!

Comment: it's working, press ctrl+f5 to reload page and check

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include bootstrap JavaScript CDN file, so you mobile menu button's click event is not triggering anything. Include below line at the bottom of your html body,

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```